# Using parameterised column filter and column sort direction

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a stored procedure which takes the following parameters:

```
@orderByColumn
@sortDir
@columnName
@filter
```

How can I have the stored procedure order by the specific `@orderByColumn` and `@sortDir` parameters?

In addition, what about having a `WHERE` clause and using the `@columnName` parameter and the `@filter` parameter?

I would not want to do any dynamic SQL concatenation if it can be avoided.

So for example, I was thinking something like the following:

```
SELECT 
    [col1], [col2], [col3]
FROM 
    [myTable]
WHERE 
    @columnName = @filter
ORDER BY 
    @orderByColumn @sortDIR
```

but of course, that is not the right way.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When the optimizer creates a query plan, it can vary the values used, but it has to know the tables and ordering.  So column and table names cannot be parameterized.

You can either use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql = 'select * from dbo.YourTable order by ' + @orderByColumn
```

Or use some trickery so a value, not a column name, determines the sort order:

```
select  *
from    dbo.YourTable
order by
        case @orderByColumn
        when 'col1' then col1
        when 'col2' then col2
        when 'col3' then col3
        end
```

In my experience, you'll get the most sane code by generating the SQL queries client-side.  T-SQL is not ideal for string manipulation.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably go for your example here using the trickery approach. What about using the sort order with the trickery? and the next part is... can I do the same thing for the column name and filter?

Comment: Sure, like `where case @filterColumn when 'col1' then col1 ... end = @filterValue`.  You'll all have to cast them to the same data type, probably `nvarchar(max)`.  If the T-SQL gets to complex, remember you can fall back to a client side language.

Comment: Tried this and gave me a weird error saying it cannot convert from one data type to another... which makes no sense since there is no conversion or casting going on of any kind following your example

Comment: All branches of a `case` have to return the same data type, it's up to you to do the casting.  Remember, if the T-SQL gets too complex, you can fall back to a client side language.

Comment: Thanks. So how would I return back the same data type in the example provided? I find that a little odd - just to do an order by clause with params